# Open a new webpage from a combo box onclick event for the option selected

Tags: php, javascript, html, combobox, onclick

I have page with several combo-boxes. The combo boxes options are populated with this PHP code. ($id and $label are collected from an ini file.)

```
<?echo'<select id="wbox" name="MPR">';
foreach($config[MPR] as $id=>$label){
    switch ($id)
    {
    case ($id==select):
    echo'<option value="0" selected="selected"></option>';
    break;
    case ($id>0 && $id<=10):
    echo'<optgroup label="'.$label.'">';
    break;
    case ($id>10 && $id<=20):
    echo'</optgroup>';
    break;
    default:
    echo'<option value="'.$id.'">'.$label.'</option>';
    }
}
echo'</select>';?>
```

At the end a submit button is clicked, and the values are handed off to another php script that redirects the user to a specific web page.

I would like to be able to direct the user to the selected page in an onclick event with the combo box. (Each option would be a new page, corresponding to the value assigned in the option.)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with PHP. Show your HTML, not your server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

> You said, "Each option would be a new page, corresponding to the value assigned
>   in the option."

So, I assumed that you have something like

### HTML

```
<select id="wbox" name="MPR">
    <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow/</option>
</select>
```

### JS Code shold be

```
window.onload=function(){
    var combo=document.getElementById('wbox');
    combo.onchange=function(){
        if(this.value!='0') window.open(this.value, '_blank');
    };
};
```

Just put the above code inside your `head` tags wrapped with `script` tags like

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // above code goes here
    </script>
</head>
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Az2C/1/).